# impdp command not importing to right user

Tags: oracle, impdp

I'm trying to import DB using the below command before which I created user "test_456" and granted all the permission, I want to link the tables only to this new user.

I'm able to import the DB but I'm able to view the tables in SQL developer only if I connect with SYSTEM user but not test_456, what mistake am I doing here?

```
impdp SYSTEM/***@TMS122 DIRECTORY=data_pump_dir DUMPFILE=test2.dmp REMAP_SCHEMA=SF_RCINA_6172458:test_456 REMAP_TABLESPACE=test_456:test_456 LOGFILE=test_456.log
```

Thanks,

Surendranadh

Comment: what does your logfile show? and when you say, only shows for system - are they IN the system schema?

Comment: Yes, you're right, they are in the system schema

Comment: Does the dump file **only** contain `SF_RCINA_6172458`?

Comment: Not exactly, but how do I know what schema does a dump file contain?

Comment: did you do the export, perhaps they had objects in SYSTEM to begin with, try remapping schema to your test_456

Comment: I tried to remap but I get this error.." Remapping the SYSTEM schema is not supported."